# СУМ 20 та СУМ 11

Tags: українські-словники, словники

У цій спільності, мені досить часто наводять приклади із СУМ-20, який вийшов за часів незалежності України. І тому, я нарешті вирішив також ним користуватися, однак в Інтернеті зустрів критику цього словника (наприклад, одна назва статті на форумі "СУМ-20 - ганьба вітчизняного мовознавства"). От на які основні проблеми цього словника я наткнувся:

> 1. "Порівняння статей одразу підтверджує, що «формування СУМ-20 здійснювалося на основі реєстру слів попереднього видання — СУМ-11» та
>      «...практично повністю включено матеріали фундаментальних словників:
>      „Фразеологічного словника української мови“ у двох книгах, виданого у
>      1993 році, та „Словника фразеологізмів української мови“, що вийшов
>      друком у серії „Словники України“ у 2003 році», як зазначено в
>      передмові до видання (Т. 1, С. 10, С. 56). Можна бачити, що тлумачення
>      і порядок значень подаються без суттєвих змін. (Розбиратися докладніше
>      з авторством і плаґіатом, який відмічав В. Німчук у статті «Про
>      сучасну українську тлумачну лексикографію», не входить у мої наміри.)
>      Також без змін до нового словника перенесено ілюстративний матеріал
>      словників-попередників, які, втім, отримали значно гіршу паспортизацію."
> 2. "Додані цитати в новому виданні іноді суттєво змінювалися, ба навіть перекручувалися, без відповідних поміток".
> 3. "Деякі цитати потрапляли в СУМ-20 з російських джерел, або через джерела, перекладені з російської мови. У таких цитатах може використовуватися нестандартна термінологія".

Ці проблеми, я вибрав із цього [блогу](https://ua-etymology.livejournal.com/290245.html) присвяченого українській мові, де є приклади, які підтверджують ці проблеми, а також розглядають й інші недоліки.Також цікавим порівнянням СУМ-20 та СУМ-11 є ця [стаття](https://ua-etymology.livejournal.com/260154.html) і з того ж самого блогу (варто зазначити, що таких статей є багато на різних сайтах

Однозначним плюсом СУМ-20 є те, що там набагато більше сучасних слів, аніж у СУМ-11, однак критика цього видання насторожує, тому і виникає питання чи варто його взагалі використовувати? Згідно до цього [джерела](http://www.ulif.org.ua/page/piershii-tom-zolotogo-dvadtsiatiknizhzhia-radisno-i-girko):

> Словник у 20-х томах — оте саме національне надбання...

Того й виникло у мене запитання: "Чи справді СУМ-20 невдале видання?". Наразі я зустрів більше критики, аніж позитивних відгуків про СУМ-20.

Можливо, це запитання не зовсім відповідає, тому я хочу зазначити, що прошу об'єктивних фактів, щоб нарешті з'ясувати, яке ж з цих видань краще використовувати для дослідницьких робіт, при написанні творів тощо.

Comment: Занадта субјектившчина виходить, тобто питанньа виходить на рівень _јак кожистуватисьа словниками_.

Comment: Проблеми, які я навів мають підтвердження у джерелах, тому це на зовсім суб'єктивна думка, і якщо заглибитися у цю тему, то справді виходить, що видання вийшло з багатьма недоліками. Цікавить саме те, якому виданю краще надати перевагу, і, можливо у когось з користувачів також знайдуться докази, які б вказували і на недоліки СУМ-11, або ж спростовували знайдені недоліки СУМ-20. Все ж таки хотілося б покласти крапку і дізнатися, яке видання вважається кращим і на яке видання краще опиратися, навіть при пошуку інформації для цього ресурсу або ж при написанні наукових робіт.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ну, власне, це вирішує кожен сам для себе.

Що я можу сказати…

#### За

1. Це словник, що позиціонується як академічний; виданий [Українським мовно-інформаційним фондом](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B4) Національної академії наук України і видавництвом [«Наукова думка»](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%B0)  Національної академії наук України; з формальної точки зору «солідно».
2. Це доволі ґрунтовна і всеосяжна робота.

Я не знаю інших подібних словників, виданих після 1980 року (тобто після [«Словника української мови» в 11 томах — СУМ-11](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8_%D0%B2_11_%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%85)). Якщо щодо орфографічних і перекладних ми ще маємо якийсь вибір, то серед інших тлумачних я знаю лише:

- [«Великий тлумачний словник сучасної української мови» («ВТССУМ»)](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%81%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%97_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8) В'ячеслава Бусела і видавництва «Перун» (2001–2009). Навертає ще більше критики, яка зводиться здебільшого до такого:

  - Там **зовсім відсутні цитати**. Тобто лише слово і його визначення. На яких підставах автори вирішили, що це слово вживається саме в таких значеннях — незрозуміло.
  - Найзмістовніші словникові статті, кажуть, скопійовані слово в слово із СУМ-11.
  - Містить багато простих однорядкових статей типу «Жито́мирець, -рця, ч. Мешканець Житомира», «Жито́мирський, -а, -е. Прикм. до Житомир», «Житомиря́нин, -а, ч. Те саме, що жито́мирець».
- [«Вільний тлумачний словник»](http://sum.in.ua/f/) від [Webmezha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298732/webmezha) (2013–2018). Спроба власників сайту `sum.in.ua` (одного з тих, що публікують електронну версію СУМ-11) (чи якихось інших людей) додати статті, яких бракує СУМ-11; конкретні автори і редактори не зазначені. По-моєму, статті складені доволі ретельно (докладно, означення, цитати), але наразі всього 368 статей.
- «(Народний) Тлумачно-стилістичний словник української мови» ([пошук](//r2u.org.ua/s?dicts=15&highlight=on), [обговорення](//r2u.org.ua/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4460)) на R2U (2013–…). Спроба створити власний словник від колективу сайту/форуму R2U; загальний перелік авторів/редакторів відсутній, хоча принаймні можна передивитися історію обговорення кожної статті на форумі. Наразі ≈369 статей.
- [«Вікісловник»](//uk.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0) (2006–…). Це за принципом Вікіпедії, тобто може редагувати кожен, але теоретично здоровий глузд і посилання на джерела мають брати гору. Кількість статей оцінити важко (формально статей наразі 36563, але більшість недозаповнені, а частина не є статтями про українські слова).
- [«Толковый украинский словарь»](https://explain_words_uk.academic.ru/) на `academic.ru` (2014). Що це за словник, хто автори, хто редактори — невідомо
  (бачу, що це не СУМ-11, не ВТССУМ (ВТССУМ [є на тому ж сайті](//ukrainian_explanatory.academic.ru), але це не він) і не СУМ-20). Відома лише назва та рік, та й те лише за їхнім твержденням.

Тобто якщо відкидати СУМ-20, то залишиться лише СУМ-11 1970-х років?

#### Проти

1. Цей словник дуже базується на СУМ-11 і фактично є його продовженням. Ті, хто мають підстави не вірити СУМ-11 (через підозри про спроби штучно наблизити українську до російської за радянських часів), ті мають підстави не довіряти й СУМ-20. Хоча там є певні виправлення, але навіть на мій (доволі сповнений довіри до СУМ-11) погляд там їх (виправлень) менше, ніж мало б бути (там більше замінені прорадянські цитати на класичні й додані нові слова/значення, аніж виправлені старі неточності — на мій погляд).
2. Незважаючи на додані нові слова, нові значення старих слів, оновлені цитати й деякі виправлення, в деяких аспектах СУМ-20 є гіршим за СУМ-11:

   - як зазначено [за наведеним Вами ж посиланням](//ua-etymology.livejournal.com/290245.html), істотно погіршено паспортизацію цитат; коротко кажучи, перестали вказувати конкретий твір/книгу (лише автора в кращому випадку, а то й навіть просто «із журн.», «з наук. літ.» тощо) і поприбирали такі вказівки у старих статтях;
   - певна кількість технічних помилок і одруків (наприклад, «складникі» в статті [«жиропіт»](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=27089&page=910) або фактично відсутній пункт 26 у статті [«за»](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=27400&page=918)) — хоча, на мій погляд, поодиноких.
3. Як, на мою думку, справедливо зазначає maksymus за тим же посиланням, певні цитати перекручено. Я розумію, що це може робитися з метою зробити цитату зрозумілішою або виправити семантичну, орфографічну чи стилістичну помилку в оригінальній цитаті — але, на мою особисту думку, в такому разі все ж варто наводити оригінальну цитату та/або додавати якісь помітки. Просто подавати виправлену цитату — нечесно.

#### Моя думка

Я не вважаю СУМ-20 ідеальним.

Але, на мою думку, ним усе-таки користуватися варто (принаймні, якщо Ви користуєтесь СУМ-11).

Хоча в СУМ-20 і є певні погіршення порівняно із СУМ-11, але вони: (а) або ледве стосуються пересічного читача (бажаючи прочитати автора в оригіналі, сучасний читач, мені здається, радше загуглить цитату в Інтернеті, аніж піде в бібліотеку гортати N-й том збірки його творів 1960-х років видання); (б) або поодинокі. В будь-якому випадку можна перевірити відповідну статтю відразу й у СУМ-11. Тобто ті речі, що зазначає maksymus — це певна пляма на академічній чесності, але для пересічного читача цей словник усе одно корисний.

Comment: От такої відповіді я і чекав, дякую!)